# How to obtain the exact value of small Pvalue by using summary_factorlist function in R

Tags: r

*It appears that we cannot see the actual value of small pvalues when using R's **summary_factorlist** function, and when the pvalue is small, the function only returns <0.001. I was wondering if there was a way to calculate the exact pvalue (say, 0.0001).*

```
https://finalfit.org/reference/summary_factorlist.html
```

*Thanks so much for the help.*

Comment: Function seems to have argument `digits` that, among other things, is used to set the number of digits in _p_-values. I did not try, but used desperate means and read the help page.

Comment: @ 
Jari Oksanen, great, thanks so much